# Does working for an extremely republican company affect my future job prospects?

Tags: united-states, politics

I would like to ask for an honest opinion.

Does it matter if you work for a very republican company and then if you want to change the company does that affect on the resume for future job applications? It's a job for a programmer. I appreciate your opinion thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it's asking for opinions, making all possible answers equally valid and not useful for futur readers.

Comment: What do you mean by "an extreme Republican company"? You mean like MyPillow?

Comment: Please tell us what it is about this company that makes you call them "extreme Republican". What do they do that makes them that? Is it owned by prominent Republicans? Is it's business promoting Republican views?

Comment: If the company is performing extremist or biased reporting then this might be a problem. If it's just focussed on reporting about one particular party then not a problem.

Comment: What future jobs do you want to have?

Comment: Let me clarify... What companies do you want to work for? Do you plan to work for a company that "promotes diversity, inclusiveness, free thinking, ...." (Add political buzzword of choice)?

Comment: The answer is for highly politicised jobs: Yes.

Comment: @johndoe Humans are imperfect machines. When going through hundreds of resumes, people will look for reasons to cast aside.

Comment: @DJClayworth This is the relevant point.  "Extremely Republican" is irrelevant, but such companies tend to be dishonest.  Working for a company you know to be dishonest does say something about you.

Comment: Impossible to answer. We don't know what the biases of any given hiring manager may be, or how much they let those biases affect their decisions. In the past I'd have said it probably won't matter, but given the behavior of some politicians recently I am finding it harder to make allowances for people who don't actively repudiate those behaviors. Remember that the right to free speech does not mean the right to consequence-free speech; people can and will judge you by what you choose to support, and political position is not a protected class.

Comment: The question was “affect”. Some people might not like it, but some will. Some muskrat might be only too happy to give you a job.

Comment: It matters if the person looking at your resume is closed minded.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing that will hinder your future job prospects, is this line of thinking.

Comment: VTC as opinion-based and giving an opinion at the same time? Weird. Especially with no explanation about this one liner that looks like a comment. Do you mind clarifying please?

Comment: It's a more general comment - but I believe that having politics invade every single space is a toxic way of thinking and leads to toxic outcomes. Given that OPs function within the company is effectively a non-partisan position (compared to say Twitter's Trust and Safety team or Journalists at the Daily Wire) - having themselves be concerned about the Politics of their current company is indicative of having this mindset and will be self-fulfilling in the future. My Comment is to warn against that as I believe it's ends badly, regardless of which side of the aisle you are on.

Comment: OK, so that's a comment, should be treated as one, and posted as one...

Comment: Comments may be deleted. This is a one-liner but an honest answer.

Comment: @Brandin: I disagree. This is a one-liner but an [...] *opinion-based* ***comment***.

Comment: @OldPadawan For sure it's right on the line between comment and answer. Is it a Comment? In one sense, but it's also an answer. I see in the comments underneath the OPs question that some people are very much of the mindset of judging others by their Political affiliations - something which only leads to negative outcomes. The people complaining about Political Polarization are engaging in polarizing behavior - regardless of side - and the only *answer* to this problem (which is also the OP's problem) - is what I posted.

Comment: @TheDemonLord There may very well be someone who _will_ hire you exactly because of that connection.